# fast ML algorithms for binary classification with (large+sparse) binary input data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, binary-data

I'm sorry that this is so very broad, but as a non-ML scientist it feels to be almost impossible to keep up with recent developments (esp. in deep learning etc.). Hence, I'm asking for guidance on how to handle this specific use case:

The goal is to predict a binary output from ~50,000 binary input variables (the input data being rather sparse with about 1,000 1s on average). The training dataset includes several thousand (fairly balanced) labeled samples. I already have a non-ML solution to this giving good results but it is computationally expensive. Thus, my questions:

1. Which ML algorithms work well (i.e. train reasonably fast on a small HPC-cluster) on binary data of that scale.
2. Do they allow to extract information about the inputs (i.e. the magnitude of loadings of the individual binary variables).
3. How large are the performance advantages of having binary data? As opposed to using the 50k binary input variables I could run a PCA and use the first couple hundred PCs (it takes about 500 to recover 90% of the variance) for training/prediction. What would the advantages/caveats be?

The order of the input variables is not really "random", but their importance might be. Hence I think CNNs would not be the best idea, but are non-convoluting NNs even feasible at this scale? Additionally, it is usually only a few input variables that mostly decide the output, if that makes any difference in model selection.

I have worked with ML in the past, but this is several years ago and my theoretical knowledge is more than rusty. Also, the variety of NN architectures / frameworks etc. has exploded since then, hence I wanted to ask for some input before blindly trying out everything.

Comment: How many of the features are typically different from zero for a given observation?

Comment: @Edgar only ~800

Comment: Some folks are going to be unhappy that this is programmatic as well as statistical.  They might ask if you want to migrate to data science or stack overflow.  My thoughts: don't let the ML folks fool you, you asked in the right forum; the fundamentals don't change fast or much.  Still waters run deep and folks have been asking similar questions for 40 years, and then putting many good calories toward solving them.  ML is usually quite computationally expensive.  If I had to face it personally, I would make something like the R 'Boruta' package engage variable importance.

Comment: @EngrStudent I actually asked in both forums, but thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reasonable results for a similar problem (binary outcome, binary features) with Support Vector Machine. But I had ~400 features with average sparsity of ~10 nonzero features, and several millions of observations. I saved the data in the libsvm format and used the svmlight software.

Comment: thanks, gonna give SMVs the first try

Comment: got reasonable results (94-95% accuracy) in a decent timeframe with an extensive SVM grid search and settled for an SVC with linear kernel for now. Also tried out Lasso/Ridge regression which performed quite similar.